# Jamon with DB2 url

Tags: java, performance, db2, jamon

I am using IBM DB2. I want to introduce jamon to track sql performance. My connection url is:

```
jdbc:db2://localhost:50005/MyDB:currentSchema=CMSDB;
```

When I use Jamon, I am not sure what changes I should make to the url. I found an example for Sybase but unfortunately none for DB2.

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To track SQL using Jamon jdbc proxy, use connection URL as shown below:

```
jdbc:jamon:db2://host:port/dbname:jamonrealdriver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

As per the URL you mentioned, it should be

```
jdbc:jamon:db2://localhost:50005/CMSDB:jamonrealdriver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```